# secondary Y axis position matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I need to change the secondary Y axis position on a matplotlib plot.

It's like a subplot inside the same plot.

In the image below, my secondary Y axis starts at the same position as first y axis. I need that the secondary Y axis starts about at the "18" position of the first Y axis, with a smaller scale (red line).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want a `twinx` axis, as @kikocorreoso says, but you also want to compress it, so it only takes up the upper portion of the y axis.

You can do this by just setting the `ylim` larger than you need it, and explicitly setting the `yticks`. Here's an example with some random data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [np.random.normal(np.random.randint(0,5),4,25) for _ in range(25)] # some random data

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_ylim(-5,25)
ax2.set_ylim(0,14)
ax2.set_yticks([10,12,14]) # ticks below 10 don't show up

ax1.boxplot(data)
ax2.plot(np.linspace(0,26,50),12.+2.*np.sin(np.linspace(0,2.*np.pi,50))) # just a random line

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly seeing the figure you posted you want a second y-axis. You can do this using `plt.twinx`. An example could be like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.twinx()
plt.plot([5,4,5])
plt.show()
```